# AJAX request failing even though CORS headers are present

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

An AJAX request from a locally served page to a remote server is failing, even though it appears that CORS headers are all present. This is the javascript:

`$.ajax({url: 'http://prox.tum.lt/420663719182/test-upload?Action=SendMessage&Version=2012-11-05&MessageBody=eyJlbWFpbCI6IiIsInNhbHQiOiJ6eTVzbnV0ams5MWY5YTRpIn0%3D', headers: {"X-Endpoint": "http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"}})`

And this is a curl command line that does the same thing:

`curl -vH 'X-Endpoint: http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' 'http://prox.tum.lt/420663719182/test-upload?Action=SendMessage&Version=2012-11-05&MessageBody=eyJlbWFpbCI6IiIsInNhbHQiOiJ6MTc3ZHk4cDUyaXlzeXZpIn0%3D'`

If you run the above command, you can see the response CORS headers are maximally permissive:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Endpoint,Accept,Origin,Referer,X-Something
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Here are the headers sent along with the request:

```
Request Headersview source
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/upload
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
X-Endpoint: http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

However, I'm still seeing the request fail in the network console of chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://prox.tum.lt/420663719182/test-upload?Action=SendMessage&Version=2012-11-05&MessageBody=eyJlbWFpbCI6IiIsInNhbHQiOiJ6eTVzbnV0ams5MWY5YTRpIn0%3D. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Shouldn't the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header get the browser to allow this through?

I'm also seeing a preflight request in the network console, which appears to be succeeding with a 204, and the same permissive CORS headers as above. Here's a screenshot of the preflight request and response headers:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBPLV.png

Comment: Can you show the request headers too?  These are potentially important and should shed some more light on your issue.

Comment: @RayNicholus Added request headers. Also added a note that I'm seeing the browser issue a preflight for this request, which is weird because it's a GET request. However, the response to the preflight looks like it should allow the AJAX request.

Comment: There are several different factors used to determine whether a user agent should preflight a request.  The presence of non-standard headers is one factor.  Your X-Endpoint header is triggering the preflight.

Comment: @RayNicholus Ahhh, interesting, I didn't know that. The headers have issues when copy/pasted straight out of the developer console, but here's a screenshot which shows all the headers on the preflight request/response. It looks good to me, but I might be missing something.

Comment: @RayNicholus Whoops, here's that screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/TMRPUPG.png

Comment: Say, why is your server returning an Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header w/ a value of "true"?  Are you in control of this server?  Credentialed requests cannot contain wildcards in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Comment: @RayNicholus Yes, the server is mine. It's an nginx proxy running a config that adds CORS headers. I don't fully how the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header on the response would interfere here, isn't it not a a credentialed request, even if the ACAC header is true in the preflight response?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I believe that the presence of this header in the response will cause the user agent to reject a wildcard ACAO response header.  See if simply removing the ACAC header solves your problem.

Comment: @RayNicholus I just removed the ACAC header, but still no dice. Also, I tried setting the ACAO header to be ```http://localhost:3000``` instead of ```*```, but no luck either.

Comment: Also, running chrome with ```--disable-web-security``` fixes it, although that isn't really a solution.

Comment: Does this only happen w/ Chrome?

Comment: I think I'm also seeing it in firefox, although I don't think that firefox logs CORS errors explicitly. I'm seeing the request succeed ```[21:23:58.754] GET http://prox.tum.lt/420663719182/test-upload?Action=SendMessage&Version=2012-11-05&MessageBody=eyJlbWFpbCI6IiIsInNhbHQiOiIxa3c2N3h2dWhsZyJ9 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 195ms]``` but then my own error logging code is firing, indicating that the AJAX request failed, which would seem to indicate that the browser wasn't delivering the response to the JS, a la CORS.

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty strange.  I don't think this is a Chrome-specific issue as I send CORS requests from localhost via Chrome all the time without issues.

Comment: I'm a bit stumped, and I am quite familiar with all-things-CORS, or so I thought.  Someone else I have run into on SO is also quite good with CORS stuff, most likely much more than myself: [monsur](http://stackoverflow.com/users/107250/monsur).  Maybe he'll see this case if he monitors the CORS tag.

Comment: @RayNicholus Is there any reason that a response with the Content-Type header set to "text/xml" would behave differently then a response with Content-Type set to "text/plain"? Kind of crazy, but it's one of the few variables left between accepted/rejected response/requests.

Comment: Not as far as CORS is concerned.

Comment: @RayNicholus I re-implemented my CORS server in node.js (it was a combination of a complex nginx config and node.js) and this problem just went away :P Since I still don't know what went wrong, and likely never will, I'm going to delete this question. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Chrome which is known to not play well with localhost CORS requests. Try using a domain like vcap.me (which points to 127.0.0.1) or start chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag.

Comment: Using an alternate domain still doesn't work, however --disable-web-security works. Not quite a solution though, unfortunately :(

Comment: Yup, it's a known bug open since 2010: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743

Comment: However it still doesn't work with vcap.me or an alternate domain, so that wouldn't appear to be the issue.

Comment: Some browsers also disallow Access-Control-Allow-Origins to be *. Set that to the alternate domain as well (or include the alternate domain on the origins list)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, then you can't use "*" for Access-Control-Allow-Origins -- it needs to be specified as the specific origin.

Comment: Even after removing the ACAC header, I still get the same error, so that wouldn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I'm just telling you what the spec says. See 6.2.7:

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests