# chrome APP - node.js - PUT is working, but Chrome says it's not

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-app

I'm issuing a PUT against a node.js backend from a chrome app all on localhost. That PUT's contents is eventually sent to disk via fs.writeFile, so if I see the file is created, I know the chain of events that led to that creation and that chain MUST include a successful PUT. The PUT only happens after a successful OPTIONS request and my response to that request.

In the chrome debugger I consistently see the following for every PUT:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4000/home/bill/POS/Kitchen.130818.135938.002.T1. Origin chrome-extension://cenckmcibjncgjbokklgfkldnikknleb is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

This is after a successful OPTIONS request according to the debugger. That http IS my PUT and specifies the file name for the eventual save to disk. The message makes it sound like its a GET operation. I know its a PUT and the file does indeed end up on disk, so my PUT logic in the node.js server is doing its job and I return a 200 status. In the debugger, the PUT status is "canceled" as though the OPTIONS request didn't allow it. That is not correct. It obviously completed or else I wouldn't have a file on disk.

There's a disconnect here somewhere. I'm trying to figure out where. Something is wrong but I can't see it.

Here's the relevant logic in the node.js server:

```
  case 'PUT':
     if (path.dirname(req.url) === systemPath) {
        buffer = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
           buffer += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
           res.writeHead(200);
           res.end();
           fs.writeFile(req.url, buffer, function(error) {
              if (error) {throw error;}
           });
        });
     } else {
        console.log('Invalid Directory in URL - ' + req.url);
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end('Invalid Directory in URL - ' + req.url);
     }
     break;
  case 'OPTIONS':
     res.writeHead(200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT',
                         'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'content-type',
                         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
     res.end();
     break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not ditch CORS altogether and add permission to localhost in your manifest?

Also, take a look at [AJAX request failing even though CORS headers are present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667484/ajax-request-failing-even-though-cors-headers-are-present), which outlines what seems to be a very similar problem.

Apparently there have been problems with CORS requests originating from localhost. Perhaps there are similar problems where the requests originate from chrome-extension://...

Sorry I don't have a more definitive answer!

Comment: I already have a "fix" by using permissions. I'm trying to figure out what's going on. It's like the accountant that shows he's a dollar off and ignores it, versus the one that investigates and discovers he's $10,000 off in one direction and $9,999 off in the other. I don't like mysteries in code.

Comment: Sounds like you should then get yourself into the chromium source code and root out the problem :-)